# Split one row into multiple in oracle

Tags: database, oracle, select, view

I have a table which contains data something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE UDA_DATA 
( uda VARCHAR2(20), 
value_text VARCHAR2(4000) 
); 
insert into UDA_DATA values('Material_ID','PBL000129 PBL000132 PBL000130 PBL000131 PBL000133'); 
insert into UDA_DATA values('Material_ID','PBL000134 PBL000138 PBL000135 PBL000136 PBL000137'); 
insert into UDA_DATA values('Material_ID','PBL000125 PBL000128 PBL000126 PBL000124 PBL000127'); 
commit;
```

Now if we select the data from this table it will give the result something like this:

```
select * from UDA_DATA;
```

It gives result something like this:
[image: Present result]

But however I am expecting something like this:
[image: Expected Result]

Means it should break the `value_text` into two or more rows if the character length is more than 30. Also, uda column should have the suffix as 1,2..n

Not sure how to achieve this in a select query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [recursive subquery factoring](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6):

```
with rcte (uda, value, chunk_num, value_text) as (
  select uda,
    substr(value_text, 1, 30),
    1,
    substr(value_text, 31)
  from uda_data
  union all
  select uda,
    substr(value_text, 1, 30),
    chunk_num + 1,
    substr(value_text, 31)
  from rcte
  where value_text is not null
)
select uda || chunk_num as uda, value
from rcte;

UDA                  VALUE                                   
-------------------- ----------------------------------------
Material_ID1         PBL000129 PBL000132 PBL000130           
Material_ID1         PBL000134 PBL000138 PBL000135           
Material_ID1         PBL000125 PBL000128 PBL000126           
Material_ID2         PBL000131 PBL000133                     
Material_ID2         PBL000136 PBL000137                     
Material_ID2         PBL000124 PBL000127
```

The anchor member uses `substr` to get the first 30 characters as the value, and sets a chunk number which is always 1 for the anchor. It also gets the remains of the string after those first 30 characters have been removed, which may be null.

The recursive member does exactly the same, but working from the remains of the string as found by the previous iteration, and increments the chunk the number.

Finally the main query just gets all those extracted chunks, and appends the chunk number to the `uda` string.

You could use a hierarchical query if there is a unique key - the data you've shown doesn't have one though.

---

Your sample data doesn't have anything useful to order the results by. If your real table has a unique key you can use that by including it in both branches of the recursive CTE and then adding it to the final result as

```
order by unique_key, chunk_num
```

If there isn't on then you can get closer to your expected result by introducing a dummy key in the anchor member, e.g. using `row_number()` or the simpler `rownum`:

```
with rcte (rn, uda, value, chunk_num, value_text) as (
  select rownum,
    uda,
    substr(value_text, 1, 30),
    1,
    substr(value_text, 31)
  from uda_data
  union all
  select rn,
    uda,
    substr(value_text, 1, 30),
    chunk_num + 1,
    substr(value_text, 31)
  from rcte
  where value_text is not null
)
select uda || chunk_num as uda, value
from rcte
order by rn, chunk_num;

UDA                  VALUE                                   
-------------------- ----------------------------------------
Material_ID1         PBL000129 PBL000132 PBL000130           
Material_ID2         PBL000131 PBL000133                     
Material_ID1         PBL000134 PBL000138 PBL000135           
Material_ID2         PBL000136 PBL000137                     
Material_ID1         PBL000125 PBL000128 PBL000126           
Material_ID2         PBL000124 PBL000127
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the result which you have showed is not What I am expecting.

Comment: @ShashankJha - how so? It looks the same as the image you posted to me, except that it isn't ordered - and you don't have anything to order by since your original `uda` values are not unique.

Comment: Also, I need to break the text after 30 characters, not space

Comment: Sorry my bad, data format is correct, Thanks a lot for that but I need to break it after 30 char which is also not fixed, sometimes it can be 10 or 100 as well.

Comment: @ShashankJha - oh, right, I completely misinterpreted that; it's even easier with a character limit. Changing the 30 to something else should be fairly simple too but it depends where that limit is coming from and how the query will be executed (substitution variable, bind variable...).